# Armstrong number program produces wrong results when compiled using Codeblocks and MinGW(32 bit)

Tags: c, windows

I wanted to write a program to figure out whether a number is an armstrong number or not. I wrote a function for this purpose that'll return 1 if the number is an armstrong number and 0 if otherwise.

I used the following code for the function:

```
int isArmsNum(int x)
{
    int m, r = 0, d, y;

    y = x;

    while (x > 0)
    {
        m = x % 10;
        r = r + pow(m, 3);
        x = x / 10;
    }

    if (r == y)
    {
        d = 1;
    }
    if (r != y)
    {
        d = 0;
    }

    return d;
}
```

Now the problem is when I try to check the program for 153(which is an armstrong number) the program returns 0 and it return 1 only if x = 1. I compiled the same code in Visual Studio 2013, and it was working fine.

I decided to do some debugging on Codeblocks(13.12), and I found that,
inside the while loop, (checking with x = 153)

- after the first iteration, m = 3, r = 27, x = 15 // fine for now
- after the second iteration, m = 5, r = 151, x = 1 // here is the problem. r should be 152 as 27+(5^3) = 152

so, when the loop terminates, r has the value where it should've been 153.

What could possibly be the problem here? Any ideas?

[Codeblocks 13.12 with GCC 4.7.1-32 bit MinGW]

[My PC is running on Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit]

[Tested the code on other IDE's, worked. Also tried out on OS X using GCC via terminal and in Xcode, worked]

Comment: I think you have a typo in your description. `15 % 10`, the `m = x % 10` halfway through your second iteration, better result in `m = 5`, not `m = 15`

Comment: Did you include `math.h`, and if not, did you ignore the "implicit function `pow()` returns `int`" warning from your compiler? You may not think it makes a difference, but I assure you it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ‛pow‛. Use ‛m*m*m‛. The library function works with doubles and is a close approximation, but it might be slightly inexact. Since double to int conversion truncates, even a tiny error can result in the end result being off by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that does not use pow function

```
int isArmsNum(int x)
{
        int a = x / 100;
        int b = (x - a * 100) / 10;
        int c = (x - a * 100 - b * 10);

        int d = a*a*a + b*b*b + c*c*c;

        if(x == d) return 1;
        return 0;
}
```

Reference: http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/Armstrong_Number.html